# SQL: Parent, Child, Subchild, select parents only if all its child has a particular subchild

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, parent-child

I have SQL tables Program(parent), Project(child), Member(sub-child). Member is the representation of User(table) for a Project.

Program is the combination of multiple projects and project will have list of members. An user can be member of multiple projects each having a Member copy.

I want to display the list of Programs of an User only if he is part of all the projects in the Program. For that, i want to write a SQL query to select the list of Programs

This is the table structure i have.

program {
id, name
}

project {
id, name
}

program_project {
id, program_id, project_id
}

member {
id, name, project_id, user_id
}

user {
id, name
}

I am trying with inner joins, but, that is not working out, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done with the schema you have shown, since you have project_id as a column on member - ie. each member has one (and only one) project, and so by definition cannot belong to "all the projects".

So if you want a member to belong to multiple projects, then you'll need to restructure so :

member { id, name }

member_project { id, member_id, project_id }

Then, for a given program, you can check with something like :

```
select * from member m
where not exists (
    select * from program_project pp, member_project mp
    where pp.program_id = :program-id
    and pp.project_id <> mp.project_id
    and mp.member_id = m.id
)
```

Comment: racraman - Sorry for the confusion, I just updated my question, actually member is the copy of user(table) for each project. Also, I want to select Programs of an User.

Comment: No worries.  I'm going to have to go away and think about that one though - I'm afraid I'm not near a database now :(.   Offhand, I think something like the following, but I'm not sure it'll work in all circumstances :      select * from program p
    where not exists (
        select * from program_project pp, member m
        where m.user_id = :user_id
        and pp.program_id = p.program_id
        and m.project_id <> pp.project_id
    )